# How to view symbols in object files?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, object-files

How can I view symbols in a .o file? nm does not work for me. I use g++/linux.

Comment: nm is exactly what you'd use. Can you explain how it doesn't work for you ?

Comment: It says : `nm: Lib1.o: File format not recognized`

Comment: @nakiya: Run `file Lib1.o` and tell us what the output is.

Comment: I built the object file straight from a header where the implementation was. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: @DarkDust: How to run an object file?

Comment: @nakiya You can't run an .o file. And if you compile a header file you produce precompiled headers with recent gcc versions, not object files. You should compile .cpp files not header files.

Comment: @nakiya: You cannot run it, you should really type the text "`file Lib1.o`" in your shell. The tool called `file` tells you the file type of Lib1.o, that is whether it really is an object file. I doubt it.

Comment: Yep. :D. It says it's a precompiled header. I recompiled with implementation in a cpp file.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Instead of `nm`, you can use the powerful `objdump`. See the man page for details. Try `objdump -t myfile` or `objdump -T myfile`. With the `-C` flag you can also demangle C++ names, like `nm` does.

Comment: I tried ObjDump also. Same result : `objdump: Lib1.o: File format not recognized`

Comment: try `objdump -t Lib1.o`

Answer (score 17):

Have you been using a cross-compiler for another platform? If so, you need to use the respective `nm` or `objdump` commmand.

For example, if you have used `XXX-YYY-gcc` to compile the .o file, you need to use `XXX-YYY-nm` or `XXX-YYY-objdump` to process the files.

Answer (score 7):

Just run:    `nm you_obj_file.o | c++filt`

Answer (score 4):

There is a command to take a look at which functions are included in an object file or library or executable:

```
nm
```

Comment: The OP stated directly that he cannot use `nm`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev While that's true, I imagine some people (me at least) come to this question from just searching how to view symbols in object files, and in my case `nm` worked perfectly for my needs, so I think this is a fine answer given the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`nm -C .o/lib/exe`**, for example:

```
xiongyu@ubuntu:~/tmp/build$ nm -C libfile1.a 

file1.cpp.o:
0000000000000000 T f()
0000000000000000 W int fun<int>(int)
```

**using `nm -C` it will be more readable**, if you just use `nm`:

```
xiongyu@ubuntu:~/tmp/build$ nm libfile1.a 

file1.cpp.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z1fv
0000000000000000 W _Z3funIiET_S0_
```

as we see it's not so readable.

Below is what my `file1.cpp` like:

```
xiongyu@ubuntu:~/tmp/build$ vi ../file1.cpp 
#include "head.h"
void f()  {
     int i = fun<int>(42);
}
```