# Given two .o (object) files, how do we find the difference between them in terms of changes in functions and variables in linux

Tags: linux

Given two *.o* (object) files, how do we find the difference between them in terms of changes in functions and variables in `linux-CentOS`

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880924/how-to-view-symbols-in-object-files

Answer (score 1):

Use [`objdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) to generate a textual representation of the object file, which you can then [`diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff).

Comment: thanx alister ....but what if we want to find a specific values,...say for example i want to find the value of a global variable from its object file

Comment: the variables when declared and compiled to an object file has to be there somewhere....is there any nm / objdump / any other function which can tell me the value of this variable???

Comment: There's nothing built-in to `nm` or `objdump`, but that doesn't stop you from finding the address of the variable (either from the debug information or from the symbol table(s), depending), when dumping the containing section and looking at the output.